# GraalVM build native image failed when depend slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j, graalvm

Here is the error cause

```
[1/8] Initializing...                                                                                    (0.0s @ 0.21GB)
Error: Method 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.main' is declared as the main entry point but it can not be found. Make sure that class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory' is on the classpath and that method 'main(String[])' exists in that class.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Method 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.main' is declared as the main entry point but it can not be found. Make sure that class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory' is on the classpath and that method 'main(String[])' exists in that class.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:85)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:377)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:612)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:134)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2772)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.base/com.oracle.svm.util.ReflectionUtil.lookupMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:74)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.base/com.oracle.svm.util.ReflectionUtil.lookupMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:69)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:375)
        ... 3 more
```

the `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` doesn't have `main` method, why the GraalVM call it

graalvm version: 20.0.1

slf4j version: 2.0.7

Comment: What is your command line?

Comment: @peterz I use native-image-maven-plugin to build native image
<buildArgs>
                                -H:+PrintClassInitialization
                                -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
                                --no-fallback
                            </buildArgs>

Comment: Probably that plugin has some verbose mode in which it prints the command line so that you could inspect it. My guess is that the command line gets damaged in some way -- probably some argument breaking into pieces, or several arguments appearing as one. As a result, `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` might appear as the main application class